# self class with no function name in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to understand what a plugin does and i see this action

```
`add_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', __CLASS__ . '::  ' );`
```

I want to know what it means.

For example i know that the code below means that on action "woocommerce_email_before_order_table" you have to execute the function "show_tracking_number_on_order_completed_email()" in this self class. and I can find the function show_tracking_number_on_order_completed_email() in the class. But in the first instruction there is no function.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', __CLASS__ . '::show_tracking_number_on_order_completed_email' );
```

Comment: I believe you are calling an instance of a class, and in the first case there is simply no instance being called. In essence there is an action being hooked to `woocommerce_view_order`, but nothing is being referenced. Does this return any errors, or is this valid syntax? And if it's valid syntax, what is the outcome?

Comment: At first I thought this was a way to use `__invoke` as a callable, but I just tried it and I'm getting a warning. I think it is actually either a bug that you'll notice if you turn on debugging, or, someone is tweaking `wp_filters` later which would be a really weird thing to do.